# How to link Intellij project to SVN Repo?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I have pulled SVN project with `Tortoise SVN`.
Imported it to Intellij Idea.

But I can't use IDE for pulling or committing changes.

I want to know, ***how to link this project to a remote repository. And use shortcuts for committing and pulling changes***.

Now I can do it with Tortoise only.

How it look now:

[image]

What I want to see:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the subversion as the version control.
Under Preferences -> Version Control it should look like this:
[image]

If you have VCS set to "none" you will see what you are seeing.  Change it to Subversion and you should be fine.